# Use link cakephp with angular

Tags: angularjs, cakephp

Could be possible to use {{ somethingAngular }} inside a link cakephp, or Need I to convert my aplication to angular using html link or img tags?

For example, I cant do this:

```
<?php echo $this->Time->format('d', '{{ video.Video.created }}'); ?>
```

Error

Regards!

Comment: Yeah, maybe i need to use all filers and directives Angular ;)

Comment: If you want to format a date from php you need to parse that date as a javascript as Date object like `new Date(<?php echo blah..`;  or a time in milliseconds, or ISO etc,.   Then in angular you can use the date format within the binding like so -  {{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}